# Magento community store have any EMI extensions?

Tags: magento, plugins, magento-1.7

> I have searched a Magento extension for EMI options, but i didn't see
>   any available extensions, if anyone knows any payment extensions
>   including EMI please reply, or how to develop an EMI extension for magento? i am new in Magento family

Comment: What payment method/ gateway are you using?

Comment: Not yet decided i just want to know that any payment gateways that provides EMI options while check out or i have to build code for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is one module by Salesignitor. Maybe its helpful to you. Currently iam using it for one of my stores*(not live yet)*.

And yes, the module offers paypal/Authorize.net for recurring billing. I couldn't find any other payment gateway which supports recurring payments(online) as is for magento in India.
You can find it 
[here](http://www.rental-e-commerce-software.com)